# Django - Call a view with forms from inside a template

Tags: ajax, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I want to put a few account management pages on a single page. Clicking a link on the left side will load the corresponding view (shipping/account info, cart, etc) via ajax into a div on the right side. For example: clicking 'View Cart' will call the render_cart view and insert the resulting template into another div on the same page.

This works fine until I start introducing forms. It seems to work correctly when the form is filled out correctly. An incomplete form will return only the inside template (the render_cart, but not the containing account management template). I can change this to render the outside view, but then I lose form error and success messages.

Code is below.

Javascript:

```
function render_account_info() {
    var account_info = $.get({% url 'account-info' %}, function(response) {
        $('#account-edit').html(response);
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<!-- account.html - this is the main account management template -->
{% block content %}
<div style="float: left;">
    Account Info<br />
    Shipping Info</br />
    Cart<br />
</div>
<div style="float: right; width: 50%;" id="account-edit">
</div>
{% endblock %}


<!-- account_info.html - this is the account info template (change email and password) -->
Hello, {{ request.user }}!<br />
<form action="{% url 'account-info' %}" method='POST'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ passwordForm.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Django Views:

```
#this loads the main account management page
@login_required(login_url = reverse_lazy('login'))
def account(request):
    return render(request, 'website/account.html')


#this view is meant to change passwords and email addresses
#the commented out lines below are examples of what I have tried to get forms working right
@login_required(login_url = reverse_lazy('login'))
def render_account(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    passwordForm = PasswordChangeForm(user = request.user)
    if (request.method == 'POST'):
        passwordForm = PasswordChangeForm(user = request.user, data = request.POST)
        if (passwordForm.is_valid()):
            passwordForm.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request, passwordForm.user)
        #return render(request, 'website/account_info.html', {'passwordForm': passwordForm})
        return render(request, 'website/account.html')
        #else:
            #return render(request, 'website/account.html')
    return render(request, 'website/account_info.html', {'passwordForm': passwordForm})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you to send form with Ajax call and dynamically insert response html into main div.

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $('form').serialize();
    $.post('{% url 'account-info' %}', data).success(function(data){
        $('#account-edit').html(data)
    });
});
```

Response will contain updated form with error messages or success message.

Generally I'd suggest you to use separate views per different actions.